# Let $W = \{f ∈ D^{(3)}(R) | f''' − 2f'' + 3f' − 4f = 0\}$. Is W a subspace of $D^{(3)}(R)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives

Let $W = \{f ∈ D^{(3)}(R) | f''' − 2f'' + 3f' − 4f = 0\}$. Is W a subspace of $D^{(3)}(R)$?

$Let D^{(∞)}(R)$ denote the collection of all functions on R that are infinitely continuously differentiable.
So I'm guessing that $D^{(3)}(R)$ 3 continuously differentiable

I know that to prove something in a subspace, we need to show 3 conditions hold:

1 0V ∈ W ,

2 closed under vector addition

3 closed under scalar multiplication

I don't really know how to prove this, but I'm guessing that it is definitely a subspace of $D^{(3)}$ because that the question have third derivative.

Comment: That looks like a function, not a subspace.  And I have no idea what $D^{(3)}$ is.

Comment: Please define your terms.  I am guessing that you are referring to the space of solutions of a differential equation, but why make your readers guess what you mean?

Comment: @Randall I have rewrite the question.Please take a look.

Comment: You have rewritten the question without addressing either of the two comments.

Comment: Start by trying to show that conditions 1 and 3 hold.  If you can't, then where in this process do you get stuck?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I am not quite sure what is D^(3)(R). From how I did the question. I assuming that it mean third derivative? Am I correct?

Comment: I assume that $D^{(3)}(R)$ means the set of three times differentiable functions. If so, $W$ is a subspace since the solution space of a homogenous linear ODE is always a vector space.

Comment: When you say that *you* are not sure what $D^{(3)}(\Bbb R)$ is, you get to the crux of your problem. You got that expression from some source, a textbook or online equivalent. That source *defined* this notation somewhere. You need to go back and find that definition, and review it until you do know what it means. We can't tell you because we don't even know what book you are getting it from. It is almost certainly the set of all thrice-differentiable functions on the real line, but we can't be sure that the weird parenthesed superscript don't have an additional meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Well if $D^{(3)}(R)$ is a vector space of functions, then the zero function is in it, in particular, if $f \equiv 0$, then $f''' − 2f'' + 3f' − 4f = 0 -2 *0+3*0-4*0 = 0$, so $f \in W$.

Now take $f, g$ in $W$, and consider $(f+g)$. Since derivatives are linear, 
$$(f+g)''' − 2(f+g)'' + 3(f+g)' − 4(f+g)=f'''+g''' − 2f''-2g'' + 3f'+3g' − 4f-4g$$
which is the same as
$$(f''' − 2f'' + 3f' − 4f) + (g''' − 2g'' + 3g' − 4g ) = 0 + 0 = 0
$$
So then if $f,g$ in $W$, then $(f+g) \in W$.

The same for scalar multiplication. Take a scalar $a$, and $f \in W$, and consider $(af)$:

$$
\begin{align}
(af)''' − 2(af)'' + 3(af)' − 4(af) =& \\
 a(f''') − 2a(f'') + 3a(f') − 4af =& \\
 a (f''' − 2f'' + 3f' − 4f) = & \\
 a(0) = &  \> 0 \\
\end{align}$$